# Android Studio 4.1 пишет постоянно Auto build completed with errors

Tags: android-studio

Постоянно показывается сообщение в логах AS: Auto build completed with errors
Причем ряд классов подчеркивает красным, якобы там ошибки. Стоит перейти в класс и подчеркивание уходит. Это глюк новой версии или у меня при обновлении какой-то конфликт произошел?

Comment: кэш пробовали чистить?

Comment: @Andrew, кэш чего? AS? Пробовал. Сначала показалось, что помогло, но потом ошибка повторилась

Comment: а студию переустановить не пробовали?

Comment: @Andrew, на это я пойти не могу к сожалению

Comment: почему, вы же не проект сносите а просто IDE переустанавливаете) если что можно экспортировать настройки в копию и все, просто обновление порой может ломать привычный настрой и работать бывает невозможно, я конечно надеюсь что у вас ничего серьёзного не произошло и решение будет простым, но как вариант предложил :)